# Deploy Etherum contract to Rinkeby under proxy

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, truffle

I am trying to deploy a contract to Rinkeby using Infura. But since I'm under a corporate proxy I'm not able to deploy it.

I'm using a standard code.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const { interface, bytecode } = require('./compile');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    '<Text to be Inserted from metamask>',
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<id>'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    console.log("Starting to deploy");
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    console.log('Attempting to deploy from account', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
     .deploy({data: bytecode })
     .send({ gas: '1000000', from: accounts[0]})

    console.log('Contract deployed to', result.options.address);
};
deploy();
```

Comment: What error do you get? If your network blocks access to infura, you can run your own node, or push a signed transaction via etherscan.

Comment: No error comes, the deploy script just doesn't work(It gets stuck).
I checked the code without proxy and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your corporate proxy needs to whitelist https://rinkeby.infura.io for getting it connected to the infura.

Otherwise you have to run a parity node on your own premises, but being in a corporate environment, i think the above will have more chance to work out.

Or you can use Metamask or Etherscan to have the transactions signed from your browser itself.

Comment: The chances or something like this to happen is very bleak. Is there no other work around? 

Yeah i can use metamask for transactions, Is there a way to deploy using metamask?

Comment: Probably you can use Metamask + Remix ide to deploy smart contract to the Rinkeby and then connect to it from the truffle DAPP using Metamask for doing transactions.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i am doing now. Thanks.